# Accessing the MainPage from my UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls

in MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
 private void StartVideos()
        {

                    foreach (Uri uri in _videos)
                        _playlist.Enqueue(uri);

                    fv.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                    fvWelcome.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;



                    mediaPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                    mediaPlayer.Source = _playlist.Dequeue();

                    mediaPlayer.Play();

          }
```

in MainPage.xaml

```
 <RelativePanel x:Name="WelcomeRelativePanel" Background="#FF1F4E79" >
            <TextBox x:Name="WelcomeText"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                 Margin="145,0,0,0"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 BorderBrush="#FF1F4E79" 
                                 BorderThickness="0" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="84"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                                 Background="#FF1F4E79" 

                                />
```

how can I interact with my MainPage from my UserControl
like this

```
private void StartVideos()
 {

    .....
    WelcomeRelativePanel.Visibility =  Visibility.Collapsed;
 }
```

I had an idea of using a static variable in App.Xaml.cs
can anyone provide a sample or another idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like this, but i needed to change TextBlock text from user control.

```
<Page
  x:Class="MyProject.MainPage">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="" />
    <MyUserControl x:Name = "userControl" />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I did something like this, and it works.

In MyUserControl

```
private string myString;
public delegate void MyEventHandler(string a);
public event MyEventHandler MyPropertyChanged;

public MyUserControl()
{
    this.MyPropertyChanged+= new MyEventHandler(HandlePropertyChanging);
}

private void HandleCreditsChanging(string a)
{
    a = myString;
}
```

In MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    myUserControl.MyPropertyChanged += MyUserControl_MyPropertyChanged;
}

private void MyUserControl_MyPropertyChanged(string a)
{
    myTextBlock.Text = a;
}
```

I'm sure it will work for you too.